# WPF DataGrid not loading data

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am a beginner in C# and WPF .
I have created a user control  LogTable.atxml which contains a DataGrid and added it to the MainWindow.xaml .
The Table is displayed but the contents are not being fetched.
I think the issue is im not able to sent the Itemsource in the right way. 
[Result]Please help.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

    namespace TableTest.UserControls
    {
    class Tabledata
    {
    string A{ get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
    string C { get; set; }

    public Tabledata(string a, string b, string c) 
    {
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C =c;
    }

    }
    }



    namespace TableTest.UserControls
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LogTable.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LogTable : UserControl
    {

    ObservableCollection<Tabledata> list;
    public LogTable()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    list = getTableDetails();
    this.logGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Tabledata> getTableDetails()
    {
    ObservableCollection<Tabledata> list= new ObservableCollection<Tabledata>();
    Tabledata data = new Tabledata("aaa", "aaa", "aaa");
    Tabledata data1 = new Tabledata("bbb", "aaa", "aaa");
    Tabledata data2 = new Tabledata("ccc", "aaa", "aaa");
    list.Add(data);
    list.Add(data1);
    list.Add(data2);
    return list;
    }
    }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
    }
    }


<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:TableTest.UserControls"       x:Class="TableTest.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <UserControls:LogTable x:Name="logtable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,209,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" Height="111"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="TableTest.UserControls.LogTable"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 

             >
    <DataGrid x:Name="logGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Height="290" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding list}"
          >
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=A}" MinWidth="50" Header="Column 1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=B}" MinWidth="50" Header="Column 2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=C}" MinWidth="50" Header="Column 3"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: do you have the `DataContext` of your usercontrol set?

Comment: I have added the xaml, not sure how to set that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a few things
1. Your `ItemSource` needs to bind to a `property`.  So your code should look something like

```
 public partial class LogTable : UserControl
    {

    public ObservableCollection<Tabledata> list {get;set;}
    public LogTable()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext=this;
    list = new ObservableCollection<TableData>();
    list = getTableDetails();
    this.logGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

2. You need to set your data context of your user control.  If you are just using the `codebehind` you can get away with setting the `DataContext` in your usercontrols constructor like in the code above.  But probably in the future you are going to want to use the `mvvm` pattern and set your `datacontext` to your viewmodel.

Note: You will need to set your `datacontext` of the `mainwindow` if you want to access any information from that window's codebehind (or whatever you want to bind data from).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) is a good resource to read up on `mvvm`.

**Update:**  Just saw your `xaml`.  Since you named the `Datagrid` you can actually get away with not setting the DataContext as your as setting the `ItemSource` directly in your code.  However, since you don't have your `datacontext` set you can remove the `ItemSource={Binding list}` from your `xaml`.  That will only work if you have the `list` property available on your `DataContext`.

**Update 2:**  You also need to make your properties public on your `TableData` class.  then it will work

```
 class Tabledata
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public Tabledata(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank u for the ans Sargent.
Well i might be wrong but some how i dont find more straight forward examples for WPF and especially on binding data to widgets.

Comment: Also the binding only the datagrid with a class, can i find a sample example or if u can just add the snippet here will be helpful..Thank u for the help